# Why is assigning an OnClickListener to AutoCompleteTextView giving a NullPointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener, autocompletetextview, inflate-exception

Whenever I assign an android:onClick attribute to an AutoCompleteTextView, my application immediately crashes upon loading the activity. I've tested AutoCompleteTextView without assigning an onClick method and it seems to work fine, as does assigning onClick to other views (including EditText, Spinners, TextViews, Buttons and ImageButtons). I've managed to narrow down the error to specifically to line 24 (setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)). Can anyone shed some light on this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.matt.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    public String[] continents = {"North America",
            "South America",
            "Antarctica",
            "Europe",
            "Africa",
            "Asia",
            "Australia"
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, continents);
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void actvClick (View view) {}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/actv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="actvClick" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matt.testapp/com.example.matt.testapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class AutoCompleteTextView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class AutoCompleteTextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class AutoCompleteTextView
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.view.View$OnClickListener android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$PassThroughClickListener.mWrapped' on a null object reference
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$PassThroughClickListener.-set0(Unknown Source:0)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(AutoCompleteTextView.java:307)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5008)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:824)
at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.<init>(AutoCompleteTextView.java:220)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.<init>(AutoCompleteTextView.java:193)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.<init>(AutoCompleteTextView.java:172)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.<init>(AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.java:68)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.<init>(AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.java:64)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:130)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.example.matt.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Note to close voters: This is not a NPE in OP's code but in platform code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like to be a bug in `AutoCompleteTextView`.

What happens:

1. Inflating the XML invokes `AutoCompleteTextView` constructor, and it invokes `View` constructor.
2. `View` constructor sees the `onClick` attribute and calls `setOnClickListener()`.
3. `AutoCompleteTextView` has overridden `setOnClickListener()` which writes to an internal `mPassThroughClickListener` field. It is only initialized at the end of `AutoCompleteTextView` constructor, and this init code has not been run yet.

[Reference](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#218)

To work around it, remove the `onClick` attrtibute from your XML and call `setOnClickListener()` programmatically in your code.

I filed a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66624221) about this in Android issue tracker.

Comment: thanks for the rundown and bug filing. When I tested a setOnClickListener programmatically in my TestApp it ran with no problem. I'll edit my question accordingly.